# c# Find out the position of regex match and bold it

Tags: c#, regex, win-universal-app

I  use C# and make a Win 10 Universal App

I want to bold the whole line of these two Matches.

```
Run Run = new Run();
Paragraph Paragraph = new Paragraph();
//RichTextBlock = RTB

Run.Text = "D1 abc \n E1 \n F1 \n D1 def";
Paragraph.Inlines.Add(Run);
RTB.Blocks.Add(Paragraph);

string Patter = "D1";
Regex Regex = new Regex(Patter);
MatchCollection Mc = Regex.Matches(Run.Text);

foreach (Match Match in Mc)
{
        //bold the D1's lines in the RTB
}
```

Output:

```
**D1 abc**
E1
F1
**D1 def**
```

Thx for your help and time

Comment: Yes, but how do I bold the whole line with that Information. Thats the thing I want to find out ;).

Comment: So, is your question "how to bold a line" or "how to find the right line to bold"?

Comment: Or "what is the correct regex"? The question is rather unclear.

Comment: Okay, sorry I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your text in a variable named `text`:

```
string text = "D1 abc \n E1 \n F1 \n D1 def";


string Patter = "^.*D1.*$";
MatchCollection Mc = Regex.Matches(text, Patter, RegexOptions.Multiline);


int index = 0;

Paragraph.Inlines.Clear();

foreach (Match Match in Mc)
{
    //bold the D1's lines in the RTB
    Paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = text.Substring(index, Match.Index - index) });

    var bold = new Bold();

    bold.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = text.Substring(Match.Index, Match.Length) });

    Paragraph.Inlines.Add(bold);

    index = Match.Index + Match.Length;
}

if (index < text.Length)
{
    Paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = text.Substring(index) });
}
```

Basically, I've changed the regular expression to match the whole line instead of just "D1". Then I clear the contents of the paragraph, and append regular text and bold text according to the matches.

Comment: ok thx, but the three "new Run([...])" arent acceptet from vs, so what do I make wrong.

Comment: @DieterMüller I wrote the code using WPF, maybe the constructor isn't available on WinRT. You can replace them by `new Run { Text = text.Substring(...) }`

Comment: Ok thx, sry that I dont understand it, but "(new Bold ( new Run { [...]})"

Comment: the "Bold" is now underlined :/

Comment: @DieterMüller Give me 5 minutes, gonna convert the code :p

Comment: @DieterMüller See my edit. Beware, I also fixed a mistake on the `Regex.Matches` line (I was using "Run.Text" instead of "text")